# Query related UserRecordAccess with filtering SOQL Queries Using WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED

Tags: apex

When try to filter query with SECURITY_ENFORCED request fails with

**FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error**

**UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 31464086-35130 (-1867299373)**

```
System.debug([
    SELECT
        Id
        , Name
        , UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess
        , (
            SELECT
                Id
                , LastName
                , UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess
            FROM Contacts
        )
    FROM Account
    WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
]);
```

request without **UserRecordAccess** works fine

```
System.debug([
    SELECT
        Id
        , Name
        , (
            SELECT
                Id
                , LastName
            FROM Contacts
        )
    FROM Account
    WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
]);
```

request with **UserRecordAccess** and without **SECURITY_ENFORCED** works fine

```
System.debug([
    SELECT
        Id
        , Name
        , UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess
        , (
            SELECT
                Id
                , LastName
                , UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess
            FROM Contacts
        )
    FROM Account
]);
```

Is it expected behaviour?
I don't find any consideration using **WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED** when query **UserRecordAccess**?

Comment: @siahei , Is your class API version above 23 ?

Comment: class has api 57.0

Comment: In that case , you should raise a case with Salesforce support.